# Validating referral for email newsletter

Tags: html, email, html-email, newsletter

There are couple of ways for a website to know where a user comes from, like search engine, social platforms, email newsletter, etc. Great way to monitor traffic and assess campaigns.

If a website sends regular newsletter, it also gives the option of managing subscriptions. One clicks on the link and can choose to set the frequency or entirely stop letters altogether among other settings.

But what if, for eg, A sends the newsletter to her friend B, B somehow decides to stop receiving any mails from A decides to unsubscribe! But effectively A gets screwed.

So is there anyway for a website to know that the request to get unsubscribed actually came from another email account and not its original subscriber?

I am not aware if Mailchimp or other services know how to handle this, so pls guide me so.

Of course there are couple of other ways to authenticate like to login and then change but I have seen many newsletter straight away unsubscribing without even confirming the request. I am not aware if they do some sort of *check* before doing that. But this can also be used to tell something to the website about its letter, like A forwarded to B but B did not like.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can expect to be able to identify a user in this way is to see of they have a cookie previously issued with a session, that you can associate with the user's account, that was authenticated by a login on your site.

Alternately, you can ask users to email the word "unsubscribe" in a message from the original account instead of depending on a link.